# Invalid identifier on ApiPlatform 2.7 - patch request on other property than identifier id by default

Tags: api, symfony, patch, api-platform.com

On my api platform 2.7 project, I try to do a patch request with an other param than the identifier id. Here I need to work on idHotline to update my db when the hotline update datas from a customer.
First, I had probleme on patch params but now it's ok.
The new problem is that I don't succeed to recover the IdHotline to update datas then.

I try some kind of code like this to param my request :

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CompteClientRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    inputFormats: ['json' => ['application/merge-patch+json']],
    operations: 
[
    new Patch(
        inputFormats: ['json'],
        denormalizationContext:['groups'=>['CompteClient:item:patch']], 
        // validationContext:['groups'=>['app_compte_client']], 
        uriTemplate:'modifier/compte_client',
        controller: ModifierCompteClientParIdHotline::class,
        openapiContext:[
            'summary' => 'Modifier un compte client par son id hotline',
            'description' => 'Modifie un compte si trouvé',
            'parameters' => [
                [
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'in' => 'query',
                    'required' => true,
                    'name' => 'idHotline'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        paginationEnabled: false,
        name: 'modifier_par_id_hotline'
    ),
```

and this :

```
new Patch(
        inputFormats: ['json'],
        denormalizationContext:['groups'=>['CompteClient:item:patch']], 
        // validationContext:['groups'=>['app_compte_client']], 
        uriTemplate:'modifier/compte_client/{idHotline}',
        controller: ModifierCompteClientParIdHotline::class
),
```

All of this without successn and error saying :

```
"@context": "/apip/contexts/Error",
"@type": "hydra:Error",
"hydra:title": "An error occurred",
"hydra:description": "Invalid identifier value or configuration.",
```

Comment: "Error" sounds like you are facing any specific error message? Can you share it?

Comment: Hello, I update my post with the error message ! Sorry about that

Comment: According to API platform docs, every item operation needs to include an identifier for the corresponding resource: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/

If hotline is a separate API resource, you should be able to PATCH it using it's own operation PATCH `/hotlines/{id}`

However if you are using some kind of noSQL and need to access an embedded object inside of customer, I suggest something like `/customers/{id}/hotlines/{hotlineId}` with a custom controller: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/

Comment: Alrigth, thanks for your response ! 
I get around the problem with a first api request to get the id from "CompteClient' by idHotline whitch wasn't difficult, and then I can do a classic path with this Id.